# Objective C UIActionSheet custom button color

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to change the color of the button in my `UIActionSheet`. The problem (a really weird problem) is that if the orientation of the device is Landscape the button color doesn't change!
Some screenshot:
[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

I can't figure out why!

Here's the code:

```
- (void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
[actionSheet.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _currentView, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([_currentView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [((UIButton *)_currentView).titleLabel setTextColor:[[MSAppDelegate sharedInstance] defaultColor]];
    }
}];
/*
for (UIView *subview in actionSheet.subviews) {
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subview;
        [button setTitleColor:[[MSAppDelegate sharedInstance] defaultColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[[MSAppDelegate sharedInstance] defaultColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)subview;
        label.textColor = [[MSAppDelegate sharedInstance] defaultColor];
    }
}
 */
}
```

I also tried the commented code, both work in Portrait but not in Landscape!

By the way either in Landscape and in Portrait the code is executed!

If you want to see all the code here's the [link](http://pastebin.com/vQDjM1JA)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this will stop working as soon you have to scroll through your options. At that point all options will be presented on a UItableView.

Comment: You're wrong, it works as it should be! That's not the problem!

Comment: obviously it does not, either you didnt have to ask how to solve it. In Landscape the ActionSheet presents its buttons in a TableView, in Portrait not. So your Approach works in Portrait, but not in Landscape.

Comment: But debugging the subview was an instance of UIActionSheetButton, not UITableViewCell!

Comment: that is because there are still a certain amount of UIActionSheetButtons also they are hidden (dont know why apple adds hidden Buttons). The last Subview should have a UITableView as its Child.

Comment: Well thank you then! I hate when Apple do this kind of strange things!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could Subclass the `UIActionSheet` class and implement the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` selector:

```
@interface MSActionSheet : UIActionSheet
@end

@implementation MSActionSheet

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[cell subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id v, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [[v subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id v2, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([v2 isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                [(UILabel *)v2 setTextColor:[[MSAppDelegate sharedInstance] defaultColor]];
            }
        }];
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will try as soon as I can, but debugging the subview was an instance of UIActionSheetButton, not UITableViewCell!

Answer (score 1):

use this method to set button title color then i am sure your problem will solve

```
[[[actionSheet valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setTitleColor:[[MSAppDelegate sharedInstance] defaultColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: works for me... what about background color of cancel button, backgroundcolor property changes color but not properly